# Has the community for the jQuery HighlightFade plugin died?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-highlightfade

I'm currently using the jQuery [HighlightFade](http://jquery.offput.ca/) plugin and can't seem to find if anyone is working on the next version (beyond 0.7 that is).  I only went out looking for a new version because after I updated my jQuery.UI from 1.5.x to 1.7.x - the plugin doesn't work for IE 6/7/8 anymore (not sure if this plugin depends on jQuery UI, but I went searching anyway)

If someone knows why the 0.7 version of this plugin might not work w/ the latest release of jQuery UI - let me know.  Also, if anyone knows the status of the plugin (or if you could recommend a replacement if this plugin is dead in the water)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of the highlightFade plugin is now available in jQuery 1.2 using the animate effects method.

From http://jquery.offput.ca/highlightFade/

> YAY! This plugin has finally acheived obsolesence. jQuery 1.2 finally came out after a long and protracted 1.1 release and with it came an upgrade to the effect system. In particular it now allows for custom animations. John Resig released an official jQuery plugin along with 1.2 that added borders and background animations so now it works even better than before and has the bemefit of the full support of the jQuery team. You can find the site for the new official animation plugin at the jquery plugin repository. Meanwhile, the old homepage which demos the now unmaintained highlightFade plugin can be found here.

To animate colors, you will need the complimentary "Color Animations" plugin.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Answer (score 0):

I found it curious that there's no code example of how to do the classic "highlight fade" with jQuery 1.2:

`$('#someDiv').effects('highlight')`